# Unknown processes?

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

Recently I downloaded something from the internet and I got a few viruses (all adware). I cleaned it all up, but what I realized after restarting my PC is that I have a few new processes on my task manager.

They are Hexit *32 (description xrc), hnsy2CF1.tmp *32, jnso1673.tmp *32 and knsiF9F7.tmpfs *32. and their descriptions are their names, nothing else.

So, are those processes some normal stuff or are they something serious and what should I do?

Comment: What antimalware are you using on the Windows 7 laptop?

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely still infected.

This almost always happens when you visit one of those pirate video sites that requires you to "Update your video player".  Never do that.

You can try restoring to a previous restore point. If that doesn't work, you may find you need an experienced person who can sleuth through your hard drive and registry to remove the garbage.

Considering the possibility that you may have a key logger installed, you might want to get on another computer and change all of your passwords on sites, especially email and banking.

Comment: If you're directing this question to me, I run Linux, which protects me from most (not all) of this bs.